# Visual Studio C# camelCase code completion

Tags: c#, autocomplete, visual-studio-2015

I have used another IDE (Xamarin Studio on Mac) where you can type the first letters of a camel-cased variable/function/etc and it will guess that is the word you want.

Example (Xamarin Studio)

- I have a long variable: myCoolPageModel
- I type "mcpm" and the IDE guesses that I want "myCoolPageModel" because each consecutive character matches the first letter of the camel-case.

Is this possible in Visual Studio? (2015 Community Edition)

Answer (score 1):

to make camel casing code completion work in visual studio you must write the first letter of each word uppercase. in VS2013 it does work, I mean when I type "console.wl" it shows me WriteLine but in VS2017 you must type "Console.WL" to show the appropriate method.